# Appendices: Hyperref doesn't match table of contents

Tags: hyperref, appendices

On Adobe Acrobat Reader "Appendices" is on the same level like the individual appendix chapters. Is there any chance to change the Adobe representation so that it looks like in the table of contents ( = subordinate Chapter One and Two to "Appendices")?

[image]

**MWE**:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,parskip=half]{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\renewcommand\appendixtocname{Appendices}
\renewcommand\appendixpagename{Appendices}
\let\appendixpagenameorig\appendixpagename

\begin{document}

  \tableofcontents

  \begin{appendices}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}
    \makeatletter
    \addtocontents{toc}{%
      \begingroup
      \let\protect\l@chapter\protect\l@section
      \let\protect\l@section\protect\l@subsection
    }
    \makeatother

    \chapter{Chapter One}
    \chapter{Chapter Two} 
  \end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The stuff that you do to make the chapter entries appear as sections, does not change the fact that they are of type `chapter` in the `.toc` file which is presumably what is being used to build the bookmark list. You might have luck using some of the stuff from the `bookmark` package.

Comment: Another method is to make the `appendencies` marker into a `part` marker instead of the default `chapter`

Answer (score 1):

The whole trouble is because `\chapter` is used whereas appendices are sections in many cases, but it is possible to shift the bookmark level by changing `toclevel@chapter` etc by increasing by one.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,parskip=half]{report}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{etoolbox}    
\usepackage[bookmarksopen,bookmarksopenlevel=2]{hyperref}


\makeatletter

\apptocmd{\appendices}{%
  \renewcommand{\toclevel@chapter}{1}% Shift the chapter level to 1 ('section')
  \renewcommand{\toclevel@section}{\the\numexpr\toclevel@chapter+1}
  \renewcommand{\toclevel@subsection}{\the\numexpr\toclevel@section+1}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}
    \addtocontents{toc}{%
       \begingroup
       \let\protect\l@chapter\protect\l@section
       \let\protect\l@section\protect\l@subsection
     }%
   }{}{}


\AfterEndEnvironment{appendices}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}%  Close the group
}

\makeatother

\renewcommand\appendixtocname{Appendices}
\renewcommand\appendixpagename{Appendices}
\let\appendixpagenameorig\appendixpagename

\begin{document}

  \tableofcontents

  \chapter{Foo}

  \begin{appendices}


    \chapter{Chapter One}
    \section{Foo section}
    \chapter{Chapter Two} 
  \end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

[image]